# Does the multi-threaded support of Queue exhibit overthread even when used for just one thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, queue

Multi-threading usually means locking critical sections, etc.  So I can't help but wonder, in a single-threaded program or a multi-threaded program but where the queue is just used in one particular thread, is there some (unnecessary) locking type of overhead?

For instance when you call put or get or qsize, etc, does it lock then do some processing then release the lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locks are hard-coded into the Queue class. Thus, the methods `put`, `get` will use locks no matter how many threads exist in your program. The Queue is a module used to facilitate communications between threads.

Check `Queue.py`'s implementation

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self, maxsize=0):
        ...
        self.mutex = threading.Lock()
        self.not_empty = threading.Condition(self.mutex)
        self.not_full = threading.Condition(self.mutex)
        self.all_tasks_done = threading.Condition(self.mutex)
        self.unfinished_tasks = 0
```

And its `put` method:

```
def put(self, item, block=True, timeout=None):
    ...
    self.not_full.acquire()
    try:
        if self.maxsize > 0:
            ...
            elif timeout is None:
                while self._qsize() == self.maxsize:
                    self.not_full.wait()
        self._put(item)
        self.unfinished_tasks += 1
        self.not_empty.notify()
    finally:
        self.not_full.release()
```

I hope this answers your question.

**UPDATE**:

Even the method `qsize` uses locks:

```
def qsize(self):
    """Return the approximate size of the queue (not reliable!)."""
    self.mutex.acquire()
    n = self._qsize()
    self.mutex.release()
    return n
```

FYI, i checked `Queue.py`'s implementation for `Python2.7`

Answer (score 3):

[`Queue.Queue` implements locking](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a08e9e84f33f/Lib/Queue.py#l21) around a `collections.deque`. If the `Queue.Queue` is only to be used in one thread, you could replace it with a `collections.deque`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - there is no getting around that there will be some overhead. The Queue has no way to know that it will only be used in one thread!

Comment: But keep in mind that if there's no contention the path through lock acquisition and release is quite fast... You're probably already spending much more time acquiring and releasing the Python GIL!

Answer (score 1):

Acquiring and releasing an uncontended lock is extremely cheap on most modern hardware. It's one of the first things hardware designers optimize because the vast majority of lock operations are on uncontended locks.